# Custom Content Provider for Multiple tables

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Can someone help in writing a Custom Content Provider for Multiple tables. I can write for a single table but for multiple table I did not find any good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A near duplicate of an existing answer.  Compare [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338802/can-i-perform-this-android-query-with-contentresolver-query-left-join-and-cas/6548733#6548733), discussing use of LEFT JOIN inside your ContentProvider.

Note that, all in all, the *expected* use of ContentProviders is to use single tables for each path in your Content URI.  It's still seen as something out of the norm to use join or index multiple tables in one call.  Not to say it's bad, just that there aren't many people thinking in those terms.