# How to get total no. of rows , when using LIMIT in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like this.

test

```
id      name

1       first
2       second
3       third
4       fourth
5       fifth
```

I am using pagination concept in my Android application .

I have to use a LIMIT of 3 rows . But also total no. of rows in this table .

How can i do this is SQLite database in one query ?

Comment: You have to write two queries, one for all of the table(and can get number of rows via cursor).

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira  I tried  this query  " SELECT id,name, COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM  test LIMIT 3 "  but it always returns me last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total count for each retrieved row you can try the following (based on your comment):

```
SELECT id, name, c.total_rows
    FROM test t, (
        SELECT count(*) total_rows
            FROM test
        ) c 
    LIMIT 3
```

Comment: . Thanks for answer it worked . But can you plz tell me how can i use this in getContentResolver().query()  method ? . Thanks

Comment: No, you can't do this kind of queries using `ContentResolver.query()`. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338802/can-i-perform-this-android-query-with-contentresolver-query-left-join-and-ca

Comment: Fine . I  will use db.rawQuery(query) . Thanks :)

Comment: Great solution. Just wondering if this is more performant? But second thoughts if its doing the count on every single row that might be a bit overkill, no